# alert() in AJAX success handler not shown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The code is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("getFilterActiveData")',
    dataType: "json",
    mtype: "post",
    traditional: true,
    data: {
        values: arg
    },
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#filter tr").live('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('filter_btn').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        });
        $('#filter_loading').fadeIn();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#filter_loading').fadeOut();
        $("#filter tr").live('click', function () {
            alert("does not shown");
            if (isSection == false) {
                $('#filter_btn').click().promise().done(function () {
                    document.getElementById('filter_btn').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
                });
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

The `alert` is not shown, but if I write out side of the AJAX directly like:

```
$("#filter tr").click(function () {
    alert("clicked " + isSection);
```

Then it will show. Any suggestions please? I can make a function that will be called in success but I don't know about what to do in `beforeSend()`

Comment: `.live` got deprecated ages ago. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Anyway, looks like you misunderstand purpose of removed `live()` method

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request is successful? It could be returning an error, hence the `success` handler is not hit. Check the console to see the state of the request.

Comment: Does the success function fire at all? If not add an `error` function (make sure you look at the three arguments it receives!). Look at your browser's JS console to see if it reports any errors. Look at your browsers Net developer tool to see if the request gets made and if you get the response you expect.

Comment: Check whether success function is executing and use `on` instead of `live`.

Comment: @Andy jquery version is 2.1.1..I used `$.on` also but still getting same problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes everything is working except of alert

Comment: @Quentin yes ajax function is fired..it goes into the success part also but alert is not showing

Comment: y down vote atleast give the reason

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , live method is depreciated long ago. Instead of live you can use the `$.on()` , `$.bind()` or something like that..

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'file url',
    dataType: "json",
    method : "post",
    data: { values: arg },
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#filter tr").on('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('filter_btn').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        });
        $('#filter_loading').fadeIn();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#filter_loading').fadeOut();
        $("#filter tr").click(function () {

               alert("does not shown");
           if (isSection == false) {

            $('#filter_btn').click().promise().done(function () {
                document.getElementById('filter_btn').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
            }

            });

    }
});
```

Comment: sorry it is half script..forgot to add this..there is no exception thrown..jus the problem is of alert

Comment: yeah still same problem

Comment: 1 doubt , '@Url.Action("getFilterActiveData")' . what's this thing ??.. this is one considered as string , i think you don't need quotes..

Comment: it is a controller not a string

Comment: it goes into success part also but does not detect that click event

Comment: remove this part $("#filter tr").on('click', function () {
            alert("does not shown");
            if (isSection == false) {
                $('#filter_btn').click().promise().done(function () {
                    document.getElementById('filter_btn').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
                });
            }  ... and just try alert(1); what's the output ?. or console.log the data object. and post the output here

Comment: is #filter a table's id ??

Comment: this starts working after 2nd click not at first..y so?